# Taking views of views allocate in Julia

Tags: arrays, julia, sub-array

I noticed that taking views of non-"fast linear indexed" subarray allocates, while this is possible on classical vectors.
Any idea, how to make this allocation free?

Here is an illustration of the behavior:

```
function temp!(lin::Vector{Int}, v::AbstractVector)
  w = view(v, lin)
  return nothing
end

lin = Int[1]; v = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0];
temp!(lin, v)
@allocated temp!(lin, v) # allocates 0
vr = view(v, 1:3)
temp!(lin, vr)
@allocated temp!(lin, vr) # allocates 64
```

Comment: I do not think it is in general possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`view(x, v)` directly refers to the memory location of `v` when `x` is a vector (not a view), e.g.

```
x=[1,2,3]
v=Int[1]
y=view(x,v)
print(y)
v[1]=2
print(y)
```

but Julia cannot directly use `v` when `x` is a view, because `v` has to be reindexed for `x`, so Julia needs to allocate `v` unless `v` is a `Range` which doesn't need any allocation.

Comment: So, is there a workaround for getting a view of a view in a non-allocating manner?